# Normal equation for multivariate linear regression

Tags: multivariate-regression

What is the normal equation for multivariate linear regression?

In the case of monovariate linear regression, using [ordinary least squares](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinary_least_squares), to obtain $\theta^* = \text{argmin}_{\theta} \sum_{i=1}^m (\theta^T X_i - Y_i)^2$ one can use the [closed form](https://www.coursera.org/learn/machine-learning/lecture/2DKxQ/normal-equation) $\theta^* = (X^TX)^{-1}X^TY$ (proof: (1)).

I wonder how to get a closed form of $\theta$ when $Y_i$ is a vector, i.e. in the case of [*multivariate*](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/2358/12359) linear regression. (I know one could use gradient descent instead).

The minimization criterion I'd like to use for the multivariate linear regression is the following:
$$\theta^* = \text{argmin}_{\theta}  \sum_{i=1}^m{|| \theta X_i - Y_i ||^2}$$

---

(1) [Proof of the normal equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proofs_involving_ordinary_least_squares#Least_squares_estimator_for_.CE.B2):

> Using matrix notation, the sum of squared residuals is given by
>
> $$S(b) = (y-Xb)'(y-Xb)$$
>
> Since this is a quadratic expression and $S(b) \geq 0$,
>   the global minimum will be found by
>   [differentiating](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_calculus#Examples)
>   it with respect to $b$:
>
> $$0 = \frac{dS}{db'}(\hat\beta) = \frac{d}{db'}\bigg(y'y - b'X'y -
> > y'Xb + b'X'Xb\bigg)\bigg|_{b=\hat\beta} = -2X'y + 2X'X\hat\beta$$
>
> By assumption matrix $X$ has full column rank, and therefore $X'X$
>   is invertible and the least squares estimator for $β$ is given by
>
> $$\hat\beta = (X'X)^{-1}X'y$$

([Longer version of the proof](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2014/derivation-of-the-normal-equation-for-linear-regression))

Comment: In multivariate case, you have to determine the minimization criterion first, since $Y - XB$ is no longer a scalar. The typical trace or determinant criteria give the same normal equation.

Comment: @Zhanxiong Thanks, I have added the minimization criterion.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let me clarify your model by specifying the dimensionality of response, predictor and parameter.
$$Y_i = B^T X_i + E_i, \quad i = 1, 2, \ldots, m. \tag{1}$$
where $Y_i$ is a $q \times 1$ column vector, $X_i$ is $p \times 1$ column vector, $B$ is a $p \times q$ matrix (which is in remarkable contrast to univariate linear regression where $\beta$ is a $p$-vector). $E_i$ is a $q \times 1$ error vector. In matrix form, $(1)$ is equivalent to 
$$Y = XB + E,$$
where 
\begin{align*}
& Y = \begin{bmatrix} 
Y_1^T \\
\cdots \\
Y_m^T
\end{bmatrix} \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times q} \\
& X = \begin{bmatrix} 
X_1^T \\
\cdots \\
X_m^T
\end{bmatrix} \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times p} \\
& E = \begin{bmatrix} 
E_1^T \\
\cdots \\
E_m^T
\end{bmatrix} \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times q}
\end{align*}

Based on your description (suppose that $\|\cdot\|$ is the $L^2$ norm), what you want to minimize is
$$\sum_{i = 1}^n \|Y_i - B^T X_i\|^2 = \sum_{i = 1}^m (Y_i - B^TX_i)^T(Y_i - B^TX_i) = \text{tr}((Y - XB)^T(Y - XB))$$
Differentiate it with respect to $B$, then set it to $0$, using that $\partial{\text{tr}(A)}/\partial A = I$ for any square matrix $A$ and $\partial(A^TZA)/\partial A = 2AZ$ for compatible matrices $A, Z$, we get the normal equation
$$X^TXB = X^TY.$$